# Continuous _changes monitoring and the limit option behaviour

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-2.0

When monitoring **_changes/** resource with the following parameters:

```
feed=continuous&limit=5
```

I receive top 5 rows on the first query, but later no notifications are received.
When there is no limit parameter specified, updates are coming, however I get the whole db content at first run.

Is this a normal behaviour? CouchDB 2.1

Comment: It sounds normal... you ask for 5 results, and you get them. What else did you expect?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to start receiving continuous updates, starting from a certain point in time, let's say last 100 entries and later on live updates. That's why the `limit` parameter above.

Comment: If you want to start receivign updates from a specific point in time, then use the `since` parameter. [as documented](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/api/database/changes.html#get--db-_changes) If you want to limit the number of results returned, use the `limit` parameter. I'm not sure why you would expect `limit` to do what `since` is documented to do. Maybe I still don't understand your requirements.

Comment: It is fine, actually, what I decided to do is first getting a few entries using `feed=normal` to get the `last_seq` id, and later to use `feed=continuous` with the `since` parameter to obtain updates live.